# How to Show Nested Resource's "belongs_to" ids?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, nested

Instead of `nil` it should say the id it is nested from:

```
  MissedDate Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "missed_dates".* FROM "missed_dates"  ORDER BY "missed_dates"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<MissedDate:0x007f8087d86350
 id: 12,
 habit_id: nil,
 level_id: nil,
 date_missed: Thu, 10 Sep 2015 00:00:00 EDT -04:00,,
 created_at: Tue, 01 Sep 2015 01:21:29 EDT -04:00,
 updated_at: Tue, 01 Sep 2015 01:21:29 EDT -04:00>
```

`MissedDate` belongs to `Level` which belongs to `Habit`.

A user clicks here on the **pages/home**:

```
<%= link_to new_habit_level_missed_date_path({ habit_id: habit, level_id: habit.current_habit_level.id }) do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
<% end %>
```

He is then brought to **missed_dates/new** where the **_form** is rendered:

```
<%= form_for @missed_date, url: habit_level_missed_dates_path({ habit_id: @habit, level_id: @habit.current_habit_level.id }) do |f| %> # This is probably wrong :/
  <%= f.date_field :date_missed, class: 'form-control', id: 'six', placeholder: 'dd/mm/yyyy' %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**MissedDatesController**

```
  def new
    @habit = Habit.find(params[:habit_id])
    @level = @habit.levels.find(params[:level_id])
    @missed_date = MissedDate.new
  end

  def create
    habit = Habit.find(params[:habit_id])
    habit.missed_days = habit.missed_days + 1
    habit.save!
    level = habit.levels.find(params[:level_id])
    level.missed_days = level.missed_days + 1
    if level.missed_days == 3
      level.missed_days = 0
      level.days_lost += habit.calculate_days_lost + 2
    end
    level.save!
    head :ok # this returns an empty response with a 200 success status code
    @missed_date = MissedDate.new(missed_date_params)
    @missed_date.save
  end
```

**routes**

```
  resources :habits do
    resources :levels do
      resources :missed_dates, only: [:create, :new]
    end
  end
```

Comment: What is the question? It looks like you need just to debug your code.

Comment: Do you access the MissedDates resources only through nested routes, or also through a first-level route?

Comment: Can you try: `<%= form_for [@habit, @habit.current_habit_level, @missed_date] do |f| %>`  and see what happens?

Comment: Also: please show us the code for `missed_date_params` - have you included the ids in that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, when you create a nested object... you don't just created it like this:

```
 @missed_date = MissedDate.new(missed_date_params)
```

if it's nested under the habit, then create it on the associated object. in this case:

```
@missed_date = level.missed_dates.new(missed_date_params)
```

otherwise, you haven't actually set the level_id at all.

if it has to belong to both habit and level, then you need to make sure that the other id is in the params.

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly what I needed :] Sorry if the question was confusing.